# Apache2 request without extension throws error

Tags: apache2

I have newly configured an apache2 server. When I try to request, say http://localhost:8080/dr/list
or http://...:8080/index, It does not automatically serves a html or php file. How to fix this in https.conf itself, so that the server will check for file with .html and .php extension if the request without extension like '/index' is not found and serves the file (index.html or index.php if found).

Comment: I have been trying to fix this for half an hour but doesn't seem to find the right solution.